# Joining same mySql table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
-EmployeeId int(11) PK 
-LastName varchar(20) 
-FirstName varchar(20) 
-ReportsTo int(11) 
-Address varchar(70) 
-City varchar(40) 
-PostalCode varchar(10)
```

Find all employees (LastName, FirstName) who live in the same cities and in the
same postal codes as do their supervisors.

I have been trying to do this problem for the last few hours and can't get it past what I have.

```
SELECT *
FROM chinook.employee
WHERE ReportsTo In
    (SELECT EmployeeId From chinook.employee);
```

I was thinking some type of join in order to make this work. The ReportsTo ID is associated with the EmployeeID. I believe you are suppose to join the same table on that column but not sure how to go with it.

[Picture of mySql Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYaPS.png)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - both as well formatted text. (When you edit, mark text and click `{}`.)

Comment: Member helped me fix me formatting. I would expect 3,4,5 members in the table to be shown when I am done with it as they have the same city as number employeeID 2 in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining the table with itself is the right path.

You can join on `t1.reportsTo = t2.employeeID` and then use as where condition `t1.city = t2.city and t1.postalCode = t2.postalCode`

```
select  t1.LastName, t1.FirtsName
from    chinook.employee as t1
join    chinook.employee as t2
  on    t1.reportsTo = t2.employeeID
where   t1.city = t2.city and t1.postalCode = t2.postalCode
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I was thinking having the reportsTo person to join their row with the employee in order to have two separate cities and postal code in one row to do the comparison.

Comment: Edited my answer with sample code. Basically you want to have on the same row both employee's and supervisor's data, so that you can compare their city and postal code.
To do so you join the table with itself, which makes sense since a supervisor is an employee too.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you could use "as" in this manner. I really appreciated the sample query and can work off this for my other sql problems.

Comment: Glad it helped. If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.